# How to do simple transformation

Tags: objects

How do I make a simple tranformation in respect to world coordinates. For instance, I want to change the standard cube (add->Mesh->Cube) to a 50mx40mx1m cuboid and have a another cuboid with the same dimensions with a distance of 0.5m in the z-axis away from it.
What I can do is use transform but I can not change the dimensions in respect to meters.
Does anyone understand my problem and can help me?

Comment: "I can not change the dimensions in respect to meters", what do you mean, you can do it in Object mode in the N panel > Dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all I was looking for was to find and edit the dimension property (press n)

Comment: Add more details about this edit as other people may find it useful.